# how to create search filter for all disposable addresses in gmail using wildcard

Tags: regex, search, gmail

Apologies for the basic question. I am trying to create a filter in Gmail to search for all my disposable addresses, e.g. name+something@gmail.com, name+disposable@gmail.com, etc.  How can I do this. Searching for 'name+*@gmail.com' in the email to section comes up with nothing and 'name\+*@gmail.com' catches everything.

Answer (score -1):

- Click on the 'Create a filter' link (just next to the search box).
- In the 'To' field, enter your disposable address:
  yourname+useless@gmail.com.
- Click on the 'Next Step' button.
- If you just don't want to see messages sent to your Gmail account,
  select the 'Skip the inbox' option. If you've used a specific address
  to identify (say) a mailing list, you might want to apply a Gmail
  label instead.
- Click on 'Create Filter' and you're done.

From now on, just use your yourname+useless@gmail.com address whenever you suspect you won't want follow-up emails, and any unwanted mails will avoid your inbox. If you suspect that something useful has been missed, you can still access it via the search engine or through the 'All mail' view. Easy, hey?